# How to remove duplicates in Wordle remake?

Tags: python

I have been tasked to create a basic replica of Wordle for my Software Engineering class. The basic model was simple enough. However, I'm struggling to fix the duplicate yellows. For example, if the desired word is "paste" and the guess is "teeth", the code should print; t(white)-e(yellow)-e(white)-t(green)-h(white). I have just started learning Python so my code may not be efficient.

How would I fix the following code:

```
from rich import print

target_word = 'paste'

solved = False 
word = input('Enter a word: ')
n = 0
while n < 6 and not solved:
  hw = [""] * 5
  nongreen = []
  green = []
  if word != target_word:
      for i in range(0,5):
          if word[i] == target_word[i]:
              hw[i] = "[on green]" + target_word[i]
              green.append(word[i])
          else:    
              nongreen.append(word[i])
      print(nongreen)
      for i in range(0,5):
          if not hw[i]:
              if word[i] not in green:
                  hw[i] = "[on yellow]" + word[i]
                  nongreen.remove(word[i])
              else:
                  hw[i] = "[on white]" + word[i]    
      print("".join(hw))
      word = input('Enter a word: ')
  else:
      solved = True
  n += 1  
print("[on green]" + target_word)
print(f'You got it in {n} tries')`
```

Comment: The easy way is to make a COPY of your target word, as a list.  When you find a green match. replace that character with something like '$' that can't be matched in the yellow phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rich import print

target_word = 'flass'
solved = False 
word = input('Enter a word: ')
if len(word) == 5 :
    n = 0
    while n < 6 and not solved:
        hw = [""] * 5
        nongreen = []
        green = []
        dublicate = set()
        if word != target_word:
            for i in range(0,5):
                if word[i] == target_word[i]:
                    hw[i] = "[green]" + target_word[i]
                    green.append(word[i])
                else:    
                    nongreen.append(word[i])
            for i in range(0,5):
                if not hw[i]:
                    if word[i] in target_word and word[i] not in green:
                        hw[i] ="[yellow]" + word[i]
                    else:
                        hw[i] ="[white]" + word[i]    
            print("".join(hw))
            word = input('Enter a word: ')
        else:
            solved = True
        n += 1  
        if solved:
            print("[green]" + target_word)
            print(f'You got it in {n} tries')
        else:
            print(f'Try {n+1}')
    if not solved:
        print("you've exhausted all tries.")
else:
    print("Please enter5 characters.")
```

**in code you check only char is not in green.**
but if you add char in target_word,using this condition check char is exsits or not .